# How can I stop EF Reverse Engineer changing plural to singular with Table names?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ContentStatus](
    [ContentStatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL )
```

Creates:

```
public partial class ContentStatu
{
    public ContentStatu()
    {
        this.Contents = new List<Content>();
    }

    public int ContentStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: It does it because of naive singularization rules - and EF tries to singularize the class name of every entity. As far as I know, you can't turn singularization off in EF Power Tools, so the best you can do is reverse engineer + refactor rename.

Comment: They are planning on a fix for this. Details http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/446

Comment: I see this fix has been posted but I am still having the exact same issue as above while using EF 6.1.1.  Any advice/code help?

Answer (score 6):

I was unable to solve your same issue of tt singularizing words ending in 's' as well while using [VS Power Tools Beta 4](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d/) despite the fix for [entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/446](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/446) being posted and I did confirm I was on the correct version of EF - 6.1.1.

My solution was to use [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838/view/Discussions/6) and it is an AWESOME tool!! I highly recommend based off being super flexible and easy to use if you are able to start over with a new tt. [Source Code Here](https://efreversepoco.codeplex.com/)

Watch Simon Hughes [video](http://i1.visualstudiogallery.msdn.s-msft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838/image/file/133067/1/reversepoco.wmv) for an in-depth (30 min) overview for getting started.  My quick solution to not removing the trailing 's' was to:

- (Make sure EF is installed)
- Update app.config connection string name = MyDbContext
- "Add New Item" to project
- Select "EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator" template from the "Online" section (unless you installed it from the link provided above already) and save as "Database.tt"
- Open Database.tt file and at line 36 add each ("singular","plural") override needed as follows:

> ```
> // Pluralization **********************************************************************************************************************
> // To turn off pluralization, use:
> //      Inflector.PluralizationService = null;
> // Default pluralization, use:
> //      Inflector.PluralizationService = new EnglishPluralizationService();
> // For Spanish pluralization:
> //      1. Intall the "EF6.Contrib" Nuget Package.
> //      2. Add the following to the top of this file and adjust path, and remove the space between the angle bracket and # at the beginning and end.
> //         < #@ assembly name="your full path to \EntityFramework.Contrib.dll" # >
> //      3. Change the line below to: Inflector.PluralizationService = new SpanishPluralizationService();
> Inflector.PluralizationService = new EnglishPluralizationService(new CustomPluralizationEntry[]
>         {
>             new CustomPluralizationEntry("CustomerStatus","CustomerStatus"),
>             new CustomPluralizationEntry("EmployeeStatus","EmployeeStatus"),
>         });
> ```

- Save file and BOOM!! the magic happens and if you expand Database.tt you will now see the Database.cs contains the correct singular form for the words explicitly set. +1 to Simon Hughes

Answer (score 4):

Figured that I would put in an updated answer instead of a comment.

> How can I stop EF Reverse Engineer changing plural to singular with Table names?

Well as the other person suggest.  Use the Reverse POCO generator

Line 61  ( August 2016)

Comment out this line:

```
Inflector.PluralizationService = new EnglishPluralizationService();
```

Uncomment this line:

```
Inflector.PluralizationService = null;
```

Now instead of it taking a View named **vwStatus** and it deciding to change to **vwStatu**  it will do a 1:1

However, If you want that complete control per table , view etc... OP answer will work for you.