# Customize pluralization in EF6 Code First from database

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am using VS2013 Entity Framework 6 Code First from database to generate entities from my database. I have a table named 'FeedbackStatus'. Its entity name changes to 'FeedbackStatu' while using the pluralization.

```
public virtual DbSet<FeedbackStatu> FeedbackStatus { get; set; }
```

Is there anyway to customize the pluralization, so I can get something like

```
public virtual DbSet<FeedbackStatus> FeedbackStatuses { get; set; }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it's just a table or two why not just refactor it to the name you want? You could change the template http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986755/how-can-i-stop-ef-reverse-engineer-changing-plural-to-singular-with-table-names, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: I have many tables like this. Thanks for the link.